# Python cmd module - parsing values from line

Tags: python, cmd, command-line-interface

I am working on a quick python script using the `cmd` module that will allow the user to enter text commands followed by parameters in basic url query string format.  The prompts will be answered with something like

`commandname foo=bar&baz=brack`

Using cmd, I can't seem to find which method to override to affect the way the argument `line` is handed off to all the `do_*` methods.  I want to run `urlparse.parse_qs` on these values, and calling this upon line in every `do_*` method seems clumsy.

The `precmd` method gets the whole line, before the `commandname` is split off and interpreted, so this will not work for my purposes.  I'm also not terribly familiar with how to place a decorator inside a class like this and haven't been able to pull it off without breaking the scope.

Basically, the python docs for [cmd](http://docs.python.org/library/cmd.html) say the following

> Repeatedly issue a prompt, accept input, parse an initial prefix off
>   the received input, and dispatch to action methods, passing them the
>   remainder of the line as argument.

I want to make a method that will do additional processing to that "remainder of the line" and hand that generated dictionary off to the member functions as the `line` argument, rather than interpreting them in every function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could potentially override the `onecmd()` method, as the following quick example shows. The `onecmd()` method there is basically a copy of the one from the original `cmd.py`, but adds a call to `urlparse.parse_qs()` before passing the arguments to a function.

```
import cmd
import urlparse

class myCmd(cmd.Cmd):
    def onecmd(self, line):
        """Mostly ripped from Python's cmd.py"""
        cmd, arg, line = self.parseline(line)
        arg = urlparse.parse_qs(arg) # <- added line
        if not line:
            return self.emptyline()
        if cmd is None:
            return self.default(line)
        self.lastcmd = line
        if cmd == '':
            return self.default(line)
        else:
            try:
                func = getattr(self, 'do_' + cmd)
            except AttributeError:
                return self.default(line)
            return func(arg)

    def do_foo(self, arg)
        print arg

my_cmd = myCmd()
my_cmd.cmdloop()
```

Sample output:

```
(Cmd) foo
{}
(Cmd) foo a b c
{}
(Cmd) foo a=b&c=d
{'a': ['b'], 'c': ['d']}
```

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Here's another potential solution that uses a class decorator to modify a
`cmd.Cmd` subclass and basically apply a decorator function to all `do_*`
methods of that class:

```
import cmd
import urlparse
import types

# function decorator to add parse_qs to individual functions
def parse_qs_f(f):
    def f2(self, arg):
        return f(self, urlparse.parse_qs(arg))
    return f2

# class decorator to iterate over all attributes of a class and apply
# the parse_qs_f decorator to all do_* methods
def parse_qs(cls):
    for attr_name in dir(cls):
        attr = getattr(cls, attr_name)
        if attr_name.startswith('do_') and type(attr) == types.MethodType:
            setattr(cls, attr_name, parse_qs_f(attr))
    return cls

@parse_qs
class myCmd(cmd.Cmd):
    def do_foo(self, args):
        print args

my_cmd = myCmd()
my_cmd.cmdloop()
```

I quickly cobbled this together and it appears to work as intended, however, I'm
open to suggestions on any pitfalls or how this solution could be improved.